# 同一人物が内容が重複する質問を投稿していることに気づいたときに採るべき対応は？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, 質問のクローズ

同一人物が、趣旨がほぼ同じである質問を重複して投稿していることに気づいた場合、どのような対応を採るべきなのでしょうか？

重複質問については、通常は通報やクローズ投票などで対応可能ですが、これはあくまで元の質問に回答が付いているケースへの対応であって、元の質問に回答がもらえないことで同趣旨の質問が再投稿されているケースには当てはまりません。

今日１日で２人がそのような質問をしていることに気づいたため尋ねています。
今のところできそうなことといえば、再投稿された質問に重複である旨のコメントを付けてマイナス投票するくらいのように思えます。

ケース１：
[WordPressのWelcartプラグインでフックを設定したのに反映されない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/14286/10492)
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/13150/10492

ケース２：
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/14254/10492
https://stackoverflow.com/q/31809314/5120044

ケース２については初回の質問が本家SOに移動されたこともあって、さらに問題が複雑化してますが……

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jmacさんも書かれていますが、「重複としてクローズする場合はオリジナル側が回答されていなければならない」という制限にはいくつかの例外があります。

メタSEの [Changes to "close as duplicate" (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/286934) から引用すると・・・

- 重複候補と同じユーザーによる質問
- メタサイトに投稿された質問
- モデレーターがクローズする場合

のいずれかに該当する場合は、回答がついていなくても重複としてクローズできるはずです。

> 元の質問に回答がもらえないことで同趣旨の質問が再投稿されているケース

この場合「重複候補と同じユーザーによる質問」に該当するはずなのですが、いかがでしょうか。

もしどうしてもクローズできなければ通報していただければ対応が可能です。

Comment: モデレータなら制限を回避できるということを知りませんでした。それであれば、モデレータに重複クローズを依頼するという方法で問題ないと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ご指摘のケースであればモデレーターでなくても重複としてクローズできると思うので、まずは一度試したうえで通報していただければと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なお、ヘルプの [質問が［クローズ済み］または［改善待ち］とは?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) の重複カテゴリの説明に、上記のようなパターンでも重複として扱われ得ることを記載すべきだと思いました。

Answer (score 15):

問題提起とは別に、個人的な見解を述べます。

回答がもらえないからといって同じ質問を繰り返すのはシステムの乱用 abuse としてカテゴライズされる行為だと考えます。そういう意味で言うと、古い方の質問を改善してもらうように質問者に促しつつ、新しい同一質問が重複クローズされるのが望ましい挙動ではないでしょうか。

再投稿する方の意図としてはおそらく、動きのないQAがトップページの質問一覧から押し出されて見えなくなってしまうので、再び着目してもらうための手段となっているのではないかと推測します。ある程度の信頼度がないとお礼の提示で着目してもらうことすらできませんし。
質問を改善・編集すれば再度トップページに上がってくるということを、特にSOを使い始めて間のない人にわかりやすく伝える仕組みが必要なように感じられます。

Comment: @jmac 現時点で+12票ということで概ね同意をいただけたのではないかと思うのですが、これは具体的にどのように反映していけばいいのでしょうか。システム的には重複クローズ(duplicated)とするには既に回答が存在しなければならないので、回答がなくても重複クローズを指定できるようにシステムを改修するか、単なるクローズ(closed)の理由の選択肢に「再投稿」である旨を追加するか、オフトピックの定義に「再投稿の質問であること」を追加するか、いずれかの対応が必要なのではないかと思います。

Comment: 回答があっても、重視のクローズでもいいです。同じ質問を2回あると良くないので、重視としてマークするのがベストと思います。質問者へコメント等で説明したら十分と思いますが、具体的に何を適用して欲しいですか？

Comment: @jmac 質問Aが投稿され誰の回答も付かず、その後同じ内容の質問Bが投稿されたとき、質問Bをduplicatedとしてクローズするためには質問Aに回答が付いていなければならないという、システム上の制限があると認識しています（[重複とマークされている質問があるのはなぜですか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)）が、この制限は回避可能なのでしょうか？

Comment: モデレーターが回避できるので、通報をすれば、モデレーターの方で管理ができます。もし毎日なっている問題なら、カスタムのクローズ理由等は作れます。（制限をなくすことは開発者が必要なため、できればそれを避けたいです）